# Altium polygon doesn't pour to vias of same net

Tags: altium, via, polygon

I am using Altium 17 and try to make a GND pour. On the GND polygon I want to place some vias to GND polygon. But it doesn't connect GND polygon and GND vias. They belong to exactly same net, GND.

I restarted Altium, but still no success.

[image: GND Pour]

[image: GND VIA Properties]

Comment: Is there any other polygon (even a shelved one) covering the same area?

Comment: If you can access Altium forums, check here: [AD15 polygon pour bug](https://forum.live.altium.com/#posts/209401/606659)

Comment: Perhaps check your Polygon Connect Style (rules) for either, "Direct connect" or "Relief Connect".

Comment: There is no other polygon. I deliberately deleted all polygons and tried a small polygon.

Comment: It seems to be a bug still. I will try restarting computer.

Comment: In addition, try placing the copper polygon 1st (GND name) then place the via and the tool will assume (or ask the user for) the same net as the polygon.  Same result that Spehro Pefhany suggested below.

Comment: I just noticed your "via" isn't a via (as defined by Altium), it's a free pad. Do you get the same result if you place a via rather than a pad? Are your polygon connection rules the same for pads and vias?

Comment: You checked in Polygon Manager, right?

Comment: is the pad too small for the relief connect? to check this try direct connect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will answer my question. It seems to be a bug in software. I restarted only once and the problem was still there. I deleted the polygon and restarted Altium again. It worked.

Thanks for all answers and suggestions.

[image: Pad and via]

Answer (score -1):

Your via is shown as "GND GND". It should just say GND. Possibly there is something wrong with the via net assignment. Have a look at the net in the properties.

[image]

Edit: Shown with free pad

[image]

Comment: The "via" isn't a via, it's a free pad. I'm not sure how that would change anything, but...

Comment: Ah so-  the free pad should have a designator associated with it. Altium should not be confused by a designator of GND but maybe it is? Worth trying changing it anyway.

Comment: Pad or Via, it was the same problem. Designator was also not problem. I don't know the problem was, but i restarted Altium again and it worked!